# Windows 7/10: Resizing window from both sides while dragging only one

Tags: windows-7, windows-10

Is there a utility or a trick that would make windows resize from the opposite side, as well as the side I'm dragging?

So, if I click and drag right edge to the left, I'd also like to see the left edge move right.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't have the functionality of dragging from the opposite side, but [AltDrag](https://stefansundin.github.io/altdrag/) has a feature where pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> and right-click dragging in the middle of a window will resize the window from both sides.